# WooCommerce REST Client API - Create Product

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, client, product

I am currently using the client-API to implement a simple user front-end to upload products. The function client->products->create() seems to work fine, how ever I can’t get around one issue. Every time I upload a product, the vendor is set to the admin user instead of the user that is currently logged in. Is there a way to set the vendor through the API? Has anybody get done this?

This is the function I created that is called by AJaX when the form is submitted (I left key and website fields empty here on purpose):

function addProduct()
{

```
$options = array(
    'debug'           => false,
    'return_as_array' => false,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 30,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);

try {

    $client = new WC_API_Client( '', '', '', $options );

    $productName = $_POST["productname"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $discountPrice = $_POST["discountPrice"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $shortDescription = $_POST["shortDescription"];
    $authorId = 5;

    $client->products->create( array( 'title' => $productName, 'type' => 'simple', 'regular_price' => $price, 'description' => $description));


} catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

    if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {

        print_r( $e->get_request() );
        print_r( $e->get_response() );
    }
}

echo ("Publicado". $authorId);

// Una función AJaX en WordPress debe siempre terminarse con die().
die();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code seems to be perfect.

The issue which you identified is because you might be using admin's consumer key and consumer secret key each time which creating a product. 
You need to get the current user consumer secret key and consumer key for the operation to be performed by the user.

Note: Make sure all users from whom you want to create products have permission set as both read and write.

Try the above approach and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, that helped, it did publish the product with the right vendor, although it also threw an error: 

Error: No tiene permisos para leer esto product [woocommerce_api_user_cannot_read_product]
401

How can I programmatically provide the clients with API keys and get these dynamically?

Comment: It's better you raise another question as it would be helpful for other like you to find the solution for the same. And also you might get more detailed answer by us there too.

Comment: Ok, I just posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327994/woocommerce-rest-client-api-programmatically-get-consumer-key-and-secret