# get secret key when i creating webhook woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I creating a webhook using woocommerce api
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-webhook

https://prnt.sc/1uqlr31

when I create a webhook then he didn't respond secret key

how can I get the secret key? https://prnt.sc/1uqmzam

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327994/woocommerce-rest-client-api-programmatically-get-consumer-key-and-secret

Comment: @MartinMirchev I check your link it's not related to this. it's related to the rest API consumer key and consumer secret. and I'm talking about webhook https://prnt.sc/1uqmzam

Comment: if you look your database you will see wpprefix_wc_webhooks table right above the api table. So if you use the example you can figure it out :)